# Editing recursive algorithm: passing array instead of string as an argument to save results instead of printing

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I have this code for finding n combinations out of an array with length k:

```
class Util
{
    // Function to print all distinct combinations of length k
    public static void recur(int[] A, String out, int n, int k)
    {
        // invalid input
        if (k > n) {
            return;
        }

        // base case: combination size is k
        if (k == 0) {
            System.out.println(out);
            return;
        }

        // start from next index till first index
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // add current element A[i] to output and recur for next index
            // (i-1) with one less element (k-1)
            recur(A, (A[i]) + " " + out, i, k - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {0, 1, 2, 3 };
        int k = 2;
        // process elements from right to left
        recur(A, "", A.length, k);
    }
}
```

it works fine and its main method prints

```
2 3 
1 3 
0 3 
1 2 
0 2 
0 1
```

However I want to save these combinations in a list: `List<int[]>` or `List<List<Integer>>`. I tried to edit the algorithm:

```
public static void recur(int[] A, List<Integer> out, int n, int k)
    {
        // invalid input
        if (k > n) {
            return;
        }

        // base case: combination size is k
        if (k == 0) {
            System.out.println(out);
            return;
        }

        // start from next index till first index
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            out.add(A[i]);
            // add current element A[i] to output and recur for next index
            // (i-1) with one less element (k-1)
            recur(A, out, i, k - 1);
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work as expected: it prints

```
[3, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

for this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] A = {0, 1, 2, 3 };
            int k = 2;
            recur(A, new ArrayList<>(), A.length, k);
        }
```

Comment: The main difference (which will give you a hint towards finding the problem) is that your first version passes a new String in each recursive call, but your second version modifies the existing List and passes the same List instance in each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case with **String ou**t works because String is immutable so that you can pass it without hurting the original.

The second case with **ArrayList** won't work because you pass a **reference** and when you modify the content of the "reference" you modify the original.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the *Unchoose* part of *Choose - Explore - Unchoose* approach in a typical backtracking.

Your *Choose* part is `out.add(A[i])`

Your *Explore* part is `recur(A, out, i, k - 1)`

Your *Unchoose* part should be to remove the element that you last chose i.e. the last element of the list : `out.remove(out.size()-1)`